# How can I make an exact duplicate of my sql database?

Tags: mysql

I want to make a duplicate of mysql database. So in my database `a` I went to `export` and exported the whole database. I received a file named `a.sql`. Then I went to my new database with the name `b` and went to import and tried to import my file `a.sql` But nothing happens. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: which commands you tried? share those please.

Comment: Are you using phpmyadmin? As the process you are following would work 100% there.

Also, is it a massive database?

Comment: no commands. I used phpMyAdmin. Then I clicked on `Export` and then `ok`. In my new database in phpMyAdmin I clicked on `Import`, then chose the file and clicked `ok`

Comment: The database stayes empty, nothing happens..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/).

Once you establish connection with your db:

File > Import > Browse to your SQL file...

Shouldn't have any issues using this

Comment: Indeed, this was the only way I got it run! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for MySQL Dump.

Run this on the command line:

Export:

```
mysqldump -u username -p[password] dbname > dbname.sql
```

Import:

```
mysql -u username -p[password] dbname < dbname.sql
```

---

If you only have access to PhpMyAdmin, then you can follow a guide. I found [this one](https://help.1and1.com/hosting-c37630/databases-c85147/mysql-database-c37730/backup-your-mysql-database-using-phpmyadmin-a704534.html) from a google search.

Comment: I didn't check te syntax of this before upvoting, but exporting and importing dumps, is the way to go!

Comment: This doesn't work, I always get an error #1064 - #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds...

Comment: Also the phpMyAdmin guide is exactly what I did, but didn't work for me

Comment: Remove the space between -p and your password

Comment: @Jarla When you do the export in PMA make sure you choose to export 'structure and data'. Also, where are you putting the command? It should be run on a linux command line, not in MySQL cli.